# Service unavailable error in PHP

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I'm getting Service Unavailable Error when running a PHP application in Bluemix which has a ftp upload method in it. How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it is because of the timeout that your ftp method is taking to upload a file. Increase the timout value in httpd-default.conf file